# TPPDF (iOS) - Image in footer section is displaying beyond the page boundaries

Tags: ios, swift

I am displaying a sample pdf with header-image, footer-image and some content in the middle. (library - https://github.com/techprimate/TPPDF)

Header-Image is displaying fine but footer image is displaying below the page bottom boundary.

Here is the code:

```
var layout = PDFPageLayout()
layout.margin = UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 30, bottom: 30, right: 30)
layout.size = PDFPageFormat.a4.size
layout.space.header = 30
let document = PDFDocument(layout: layout)

let headerImage = UIImage(named: "header")!
let headerImageElement = PDFImage(image: headerImage)
headerImageElement.quality = 1.0
headerImageElement.options = [.none]
document.addImage(.headerCenter, image: headerImageElement)

for i in 1...100 {
    document.addText(.contentCenter, text: "Content goes here. \(i)")
}

let footerImage = UIImage(named: "footer")!
let footerImageElement = PDFImage(image: footerImage)
footerImageElement.quality = 1.0
footerImageElement.options = [.none]
document.addImage(.footerCenter, image: footerImageElement)

do {
    var docURL = try PDFGenerator.generateURL(document: document, filename: "Example.pdf")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: docURL);
    webView.load(request as URLRequest);
}
catch {
    print("error loading PDF")
}
```

**And the output is below (footer image is not displaying):**

[image]

Now If I increase the bottom margin insets to some 150 i.e

```
layout.margin = UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 30, bottom: 150, right: 30)
```

**Footer image starts displaying but there is lot of gap between the footer image and the content.**

[image]

**Note**: Footer image doesn't have any white space inside it.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Hi, looks like this is a calculation error. Please open an issue at the github project and if possible provide a fully working project sample which reproduces the error. This would be greatly appreciated and helps debugging the issue

Comment: Alright. I will open an issue.